# Why would an IPv4 APN work on a OnePlus One but not a OnePlus 5 with the same SIM?

Tags: oneplus-one, apn, ipv6, oneplus-5

I have a T-Mobile SIM that, on a OnePlus One, works perfectly fine on T-Mobile's APN in IPv4-only mode, with an IPv4 address and everything.

However, when I take it out and put it on a OnePlus 5, it doesn't work with the same APN settings unless I change *IPv4* to *IPv6* (or *IPv4/IPv6*).

I'm baffled at how this is possible. How is this possible? Shouldn't all phones be able to connect to the same APNs with the same settings?

Comment: T-Mobile in what country?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: USA.